# How to import Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Ojm.png)

I am writing python with studio code. I installed the selenium package with `pip install selenium`
From `selenium import webdriver` I get an error defining the module.

Comment: ALL CAPS is considered yelling. Don't do that. Screenshots of UI are great. Screenshots of code or HTML are bad. Post the actual text of the code once it's reduced to an [mcve] along with any error messages in text, properly formatted. Also, please don't bold everything... there's no reason.

Comment: Please copy the error text in your question instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be environment issue of python. Kindly make sure you are in right environment and then install selenium
pip install selenium